# Allow Camel context to run forever

Tags: spring, apache-camel

I am using camel-spring jar for springCamelContext. When I start the camel context , it run for 5 minutes (Default time). I can make my thread sleep for some specific time i.e.

```
try {
            camelContext.start();
            Thread.sleep(50 * 60 * 1000);
            camelContext.stop();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

BUT I want is my camelContext to run FOREVER because this application is going to be deployed and It will be listening for messages from KAFKA server. I know there is a class

```
org.apache.camel.spring.Main
```

But I don't know how to configure it with springCamelContext or not sure if there any other way. Thanks

Update : Even If I remove camelContext.stop() , context is stopped after sometime and I get following logs :

```
[Thread-1] INFO org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext - Apache Camel 2.17.2 (CamelContext: camel-1) is shutting down
    [Thread-1] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy - Starting to graceful shutdown 1 routes (timeout 300 seconds)
    [Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - ShutdownTask] INFO org.apache.camel.component.kafka.KafkaConsumer - Stopping Kafka consumer
    [Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - ShutdownTask] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy - Route: route1 shutdown complete, was consuming from: Endpoint[kafka://localhost:9092?groupId=group0&serializerClass=org.springframework.integration.kafka.serializer.avro.AvroSerializer&topic=my-topic]
    [Thread-1] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy - Graceful shutdown of 1 routes completed in 0 seconds
    [Thread-1] INFO org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext - Apache Camel 2.17.2 (CamelContext: camel-1) uptime 4 minutes
    [Thread-1] INFO org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext - Apache Camel 2.17.2 (CamelContext: camel-1) is shutdown in 0.022 seconds
```

Comment: Why are you calling context.stop()?

Comment: @MartinFrey I have updated my question. Plz have a look.

Comment: How are you deploying Camel ? As i understand , Camel context is a long running and is intended to live as long as the application lives. Did you look at  : https://camel.apache.org/running-camel-standalone-and-have-it-keep-running.html

Comment: @RamachandranGA I have already seen that as mentioned in my question. default uptime for camel context is 5 minute. I wanted to know Is there any property/method in springCamelContext which I can use to let my context run forever till the JVM is terminated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a minimal example which runs forever and only copies files from one folder to another:

```
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.main.Main;

public class FileWriteRoute {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Main main = new Main();

        main.addRouteBuilder(new RouteBuilder() {

            public void configure() {
                from("file://D:/dev/playground/camel-activemq/src/data")
                        .to("file://D:/dev/playground/camel-activemq/src/data_out");
            }
        });

        main.run();
    }
}
```

Comment: In the above example if the camel context is running and some files are added to the data folder, will be camel able to detect it and copy files to the data_out folder without restarting? asking to know the procedure of camel

Comment: I am working on an application that is using apache camel for SNMP traps, the context is always running which is fine, but it is printing the same data. I mean camel should be able to listen to incoming SNMP traps and print their respective data. can you explain this concept a little bit?

Answer (score 0):

Of if you have your Route defined in a class try:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Main main = new Main();
  CamelContext context = main.getOrCreateCamelContext();
  try {
    context.addRoutes(new YOURROUTECLASS());
    context.start();
    main.run();
  }
  catch (Exception e){
    enter code here
  }
 }
```