# Where is org.apache.camel.main.Main located?

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am working with Camel and trying to understand how to use it without Spring.

I found several examples [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39004710/allow-camel-context-to-run-forever) and [2](http://www.masteringintegration.com/apache-frameworks/camel/getting-started-with-camel-3).

But when I try to `import org.apache.camel.main.Main;` I get nothing. I am using `Java 11` and Camel-related pom.xml looks:

```
<camel.version>3.2.0</camel.version>

...

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
   <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
   <version>${camel.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
   <artifactId>camel-core-engine</artifactId>
   <version>${camel.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
   <artifactId>camel-aws-sqs</artifactId>
   <version>${camel.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
   <artifactId>camel-quartz</artifactId>
   <version>${camel.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
   <artifactId>camel-timer</artifactId>
   <version>${camel.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Ideally, I wanted to see something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Main main = new Main();
    CamelContext context = main.getOrCreateCamelContext();
    context.addRoutes(new MyRoute());
    context.start();
    main.run();
}
```

Is `Main` moved in version `3.2.0` or am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`org.apache.camel.main.Main` has been moved from `camel-core` to `camel-main`.
See [Camel 3 migration guide](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/camel-3-migration-guide.html)

> The Camel Main class has been moved out of camel-core into camel-main so you should add that as dependency if you use Main.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-main</artifactId>
  <version>${camel.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-main/3.2.0/jar

Answer (score 0):

have you tried doing maven update or rebuild to get the import into scope?

Comment: Yes, reimport. `mvn clean install` and all simple scenarios that can help in IntelliJ IDEA

Comment: Looks like org.apache.camel.main is not available in the latest version. Worth checking the docs https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.camel/camel-core/3.0.0-RC1/index.html. If I change camel core version to 2.9.8, I can see import org.apache.camel.main.Main

Comment: For me, the downgrade is not a way to go. Is there any other way to do it in 3.x versions?
I assume that approach just changed.